# Creating a wave using MEGA2560 (analogWrite)

Tags: arduino

Been trying to create a wave using the PWM ports (because this Arduino doesn't have DAC)of an Arduino Mega using this code. In the simulation I use a wave form generator that goes to A0, then I just want to convert it from 1023 bits to 255 but I get nothing as output.

```
int in = A0;
int out = 10;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(in, INPUT);
  pinMode(out, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  analogRead(in);
  analogWrite(10, in/4);
}
```

Any suggestion would be great, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're discarding the returned value from `analogRead`. Change:

```
void loop(){
  analogRead(in);
  analogWrite(10, in/4);
}
```

to:

```
void loop(){
  int p = analogRead(in);
  analogWrite(out, p / 4);
}
```

Comment: Tried this before but I'm having the same issue (although the correction is great), however, I think that is an Arduino issue since it doesn't have an in-built DAC :(

Comment: [This page](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogWrite#.UxSsqdyX-iA) seems to suggest that this should work with a PWM output.

Answer (score 0):

The pin 10 is digital output, isn't it ?

Moreover there is a function for creating a wave : `tone(pin, freq, time);`